# Labels in char.Scatter PerformanceAnalytics

Tags: r, performance, graphics, charts, analytics

I am trying to add some labels to the x and y axis in the `chart.Scatter` plot from the **PerformanceAnalytics** package but it does not seem to work. Ideally, I would like to generate a chart with either a rug or an histogram on the y & x axis, so `chart.Scatter` seemed to be a good function but it does not work for me as I can't label the axis...

```
chart.Scatter(runif(100, 5.0, 7.5),runif(100, 5.0, 7.5),xlab="Series A",ylab="Series B",main="random xy")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could temporarily set the color of the axis labels to "white" (or "transparent") using `par` and subsequently add the customized axis labels.

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

par(col.lab = "white")
chart.Scatter(runif(100, 5.0, 7.5), runif(100, 5.0, 7.5), main="random xy")

par(col.lab = "black")
title(xlab = "Series A", ylab = "Series B")
```

[image: chart.Scatter]

Comment: Hopefully  the owner of the PerformanceAnalytics package will also look into his code...meanwhile this is a really useful suggestion for everyone on how to deal with this , thank you, much appreciated.